# team city api returns json example

Tags: ruby, curl, teamcity, curb

I'm struggling with getting results from the team city api in JSON

```
require 'open-uri'
  url = ".../app/rest/buildQueue/"
  c = Curl::Easy.new(url) do |curl| 
    curl.headers["Content-type"] = "application/json"
    curl.http_auth_types = :basic
    curl.username = 'user'
    curl.password = 'password'
  end
  c.perform
  puts c.body_str
```

I get a bunch of xml text

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Accept` header to control the response type:

e.g (command line)

`curl --url http://xxx/app/rest/buildQueue/ -H Accept:"application/json"`

[Documentation Reference](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/REST+API#RESTAPI-ResponseFormats)

Answer (score 0):

also you can use "net/http"

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

url = URI('http://localhost:8111/httpAuth/app/rest/agents')
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url)
req['Accept'] = 'application/json'
req.basic_auth 'admin', 'admin'

res = Net::HTTP.start(url.hostname, url.port) {|http|
  http.request(req)
}
puts res.body
```